# Intel HAXM not supported in Windows 8

Tags: cpu, virtualization, intel

I have HAXM working in Windows 7 on my laptop.
Recently I replaced harddrive and installed Windows 8.

When I install HAXM it tells it is not supported.
If I place old HDD then HAXM works.

Intel Processor Identication Utility tells that Intel VT-x is on in Windows 7 and Off in Windows 8

BIOS has no option to change VT-x

Is there way to enable it in Windows 8?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Uninstall Hyper-V from Windows 8 and you will unlock visualization in Windows 8